# How can we promote our community?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the [stats over on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing), it looks like we're doing pretty well for quality, not so well for numbers. How can we raise the latter without hurting the former?

What can we do here to promote our site to thoughtful, interested users who will be able to ask/answer relevant and interesting questions? I'm tweeting questions that I find personally interesting (to a degree, I don't want to overdo it or it'll backfire).

There are also more ideas in these blog posts - do you think we're ready for any of these? 
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/ 
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth cross-pollinating on other QA forums we frequent - pointing out on appropriate questions that it might be worth the user's time to ask that question here as well - or if we can, pointing to a question that's been *answered* here.

I think so long as we don't cross-promote in an obnoxious way it could work well, and raise the profile of this community.

Comment: Pointing to questions that have been answered here sounds like a great approach, thanks.  I'm also wondering whether it's worth the "flyers at conferences" approach yet.

Comment: STARWest is in early October, it might be a good target - anyone going?  I don't have the $$ and my company won't send me :(